# Identify the extension of files resided in a folder for processing files using hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, file-extension

I need to process a folder of text files. Text files can be of any extensions.

For each extension we need seperate custom reader for processing that file in hadoop.

```
folder1/
   Data1.pdf
   Data2.xml
   Data3.html
   Data4.txt
   Data5.csv
```

What will be the better way to get the extensions of files in a folder and set Custom InputFormat for my MR Job?

What I did so far is

Driver

```
FileStatus[] stati = null;
try {
    stati = fs.listStatus(in);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (FileStatus status : stati) {
    Path path = status.getPath();
    System.out.println("Path----> "+path);
    /*
     * get file extension
     */
    String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(path.toString());
    System.out.println("ext--->"+ext);
    if(ext.equals("pdf")){
          //custom pdf record reader
         job.setInputFormatClass(PdfInputFormat.class);
    }
    else{
         job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    }
}
```

But this will not work witin  folder1, but if folder1 only contains .pdf files this works fine.

Am I missing out anything?

Hope this will not work fine as I am iterating through the folder(say folder2--> Data5.pdf,Data4.csv).This setInputFormatClass will not show any impact to 
TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in) as inputformat will set with the last iteration value for Data4.csv.

```
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    try {
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
```

**EDIT**

```
Job job = null;
try {
 job = new Job(conf, "TextMining");
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
 * check entension
 */
for (FileStatus status : stati) {
 Path path = status.getPath();
 System.out.println("Path----> "+path);
 /*
  * get file extension
  */
 String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(path.toString());
 System.out.println("ext--->"+ext);
 if(ext.equals("pdf")){
       System.out.println("Pdf File Format");
      // MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path,PdfInputFormat.class, PDFStemmingMapper.class);
       job.setInputFormatClass(PdfInputFormat.class);
 }
 else if(ext.equals("xlsx")){ 
       System.out.println("Excel File Format");
       job.setInputFormatClass(ExcelInputFormat.class);
 }
 else{
       System.out.println("normal Text File");
       job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
 }
}
job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
//job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


//   try {
  //    TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
  //   } catch (IOException e) {
  //    e.printStackTrace();
  //   }
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
```

I am trying to achieve somewhat like above.
But this is not giving any output.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

From Context, get Input Split and then get Path & name from the path.

`Context => getInputSplit() => getPath => getName()`

Once you get the name, find `lastIndexOf(".")`  and substring from that index.

Now you have extension in the sub string and use it for comparison.

**EDIT:**

Is below approach feasible for you?

1. Have separate Mapper for each type of your extension.
2. Add below lines in Driver class.

   ```
   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path_pdf,inputFormatClass, PDFMapper.class)

   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path_xml, inputFormatClass,XMLMapper.class)

   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path_html,inputFormatClass,HTMLMapper.class)

   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path_csv,inputFormatClass,CVSMapper.class)
   ```

Comment: Should I get the input split ->getPath->getName and check the extension or get the filestatus in Driver and iterate through filestatus and get path? Which is the better way of doing that?Because we need to set the "setInputFormatClass" from driver class right?

Comment: First one is better.

Comment: Fine. But still one doubt remaning."Context => getInputSplit() => getPath => getName()" shld be donr in mapper class right? But How will I set custom input Format in Driver class for my different file formats?

Comment: How about using MultipleInputs.addInputPath() and have different Mapper  for each type of extension?

Comment: Is there any thing with different mappers. We can give the same mapper itself right?. The issue is with taking a folder as input.If I am giving just the file as my input every thing works fine. I am trying to achieve the same in folder input. Please see my edit

Comment: I see one advantage. Data locality will be improved with a specific file. By providing single extension file, Hadoop knows Mapper nodes of a particular file and select those nodes as Mapper. If you use one Mapper for different type of files and these files are huge, data locality may be lost.

Comment: Ok fine. Will use different mappers. So to process all files in folder Shld I iterate through "for (FileStatus status : stati) { Driver configuration}" and process each file?

Comment: If you files are limited like 5 or 6, add 5-6 statements as my proposed answer.  Otherwise you can iterate through FileStatus list and assign  different Mapper.

Comment: But if I iterate through FileStatus and assign different mappers. After one iteration my output folder will be filled with 1 st file's processing result. So inorder to process next file,I need to create folder with iteration count. Am I able to get all results in one folder? Any way for that?

Comment: Your_output-dir/extension-type+iter-count/ can be output directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99674/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-ravindra).

Answer (score 0):

For Mappers, the input expected is a record (indicated by the value). How this record is constructed and passed to map method is handled by InputFormat.

Ex: Default input format, TextInputFormat, will consider one line in a file as a record. This usually works well for txt/xsv files.

For other file types, better approach is to use a Custom InputFormat, which knows how to represent one record. (In XML, a record can be one sub block)

If you already have InputFormat classes for all the file types you've identified, then you can use MultipleInputs.

Look at the Javadoc here
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html

Identifying the extension can be done using FileSystem APIs

Comment: How can I move on with MultipleInputs? Is that sufficient for my case. MultipleInputs helps in joining different files like [this](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/12/joining-two-files-using-multipleinput.html).whether MultipleInputs do more than that

Comment: MultipleInputs are typically used to process different types of file, to produce a common output that is used as it is OR that can be joined further for additional processing. Ex: 1). Extracting Order details from different types of files (XML, JSON, TXT etc.). 2) Join is another type of use case, where say Order & Item details are in different files & you want one output record combining the details of both. **What is your use case?**

Comment: 1 st one is my use case.I need to process files in a folder with different file extension

Comment: Then, first thing you need to have is the InputFormats for all the file types. Text is there by default, others you need to identify or write on your own.

Comment: Yes every InputFormat is identified. The issue is how to how to process a folder containing different file extensions. Whether to iterate through FileStatus to do the same or any other method? And my expected output will be like 1 folder containing all files after stop word remova;

Comment: Using FileStatus is the approach you should be using.

Comment: yes but while doing that I will only get my output files in differenr folders wrt iteration count. do u have any suggestion to get all those output files in 1 folder?

Comment: How about using MultipleOutputs, but this will enforce you use a reducer. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99764/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-ramu-malur).